# Is the HTML tag in a JSF 2 composite component required?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

In [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4793959/1523090) BalusC states that

> any tags outside <ui:composition> are unnecessary as they are ignored by Facelets anyway

Now I wonder if the same holds for composite components? Is it valid to omit the HTML tags and the doctype declaration in the following example code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="title" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
  <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.title}" />
  ...

</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, I noticed that we need at least one XML root element. Is this the only reason for the presence of the HTML tag?

Comment: Yes (to the question in the comment)